# why do we initilizing culter on controller initialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internationalization

Here I am using Internationalization but after research on that Culter and UICulter is initialized in Controller initialization Why?
And I also comment that code initialized code but work as it is.
So why we initialized at controller level

`here is my code`

```
 protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        //if (Session["CurrentCulture"] != null)
        //{
        //    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Session["CurrentCulture"].ToString());
        //    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Session["CurrentCulture"].ToString());
        //}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is the initialization of Controller is done before every action it executes and model binder in the pipeline of Asp.Net MVC.

[image]

If you set `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` at action level, it works fine to display the information in different languages on razor views.

However, if you need to provide validation message in different languages with the help of Validation attribute, for example, [RequiredAttribute](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/requiredattributeattribute.cs,7ba3fd27853f830a), you must set them in initialization not the action level because model binders is before the action execution.